# How do you change processor (target of .ioc file) in a working STM32IDE project

Tags: ide, stm32, cpu-architecture

I have a project originally targeted at the 64 pin version of the STM32G474RET6 processor.

Due to component shortages only the STM32G474VET6 (100 pin version)
was available to us and so a prototype was made using this.
This works with the code generated for the 64 pin generated device.

What I would like to do, moving on from prototype stage, is
change the project so that it uses the new 100 pin processor instead.

Apart from completely starting from afresh, with a new project and pulling all the s/w written into it and re-installing and testing the DSP plus other libraries, I cannot see a way of achieving this.
Ideally I'd like to be able to simply change the processor type in the project but cannot find a way of doing this.

Comment: I had to do something similar and did not find an "easy" solution. I basically did as you said: made a new project, and ported everything into that.